# provide Azure Key Vault password to Zabbix login API

Tags: azure, zabbix, azure-keyvault

how to pass in password to Zabbix API json login script, as password is saved in Azure Key Vault as secret.

```
$json_login = '
            {
                "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                "method": "user.login",
                "params": {
                    "user": "ZabbixUser",
                    "password": "**Need to getfrom Azure Key Vault secret**"
                },
                "id": 1,
                "auth": null
                }'

$output = Invoke-RestMethod -ContentType application/json -Method Post -Uri $uri -Body $json_login
Write-Output $output
```

Using below is not secure, as provides as a plain text:

```
$Password = (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "MyVault" -Name "MySecretName").SecretValueText
```

Calling login to Zabbix from powershell.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the format of your request body `$json_login` like below, after running `$Password = (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "MyVault" -Name "MySecretName").SecretValueText`, pass the `$Password` directly to the body, then there will not be a plain text, it is secure, because **only people with secret get permission in the access policy of your keyvault** can get it from `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret`.

```
$json_login = @{
                jsonrpc = "2.0"
                method = "user.login"
                params = @{
                    user = "ZabbixUser"
                    password= $Password
                }
                id = "1"
                auth= "null"
                }
```

For more details about the usage, see Example 2 in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7#examples).

Comment: Hmm... I was worried as $password variable result will have a plain text, not something like "System.Security.SecureString" you normally get from PSCredentials.

Comment: @Mund If you use SecureString in the request body, I suppose it will not work, from the [doc](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/api/reference/user/login), the `password` should be `string`. And I think my solution is secure, the secret value will not expose in the text and if someone does not have the permission in the access policy, he will not get the secret anyway. The script just works for someone who has the permission.